# How to get selected shape in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, selection, shapes

I have inserted a smart art, and converted it to shapes. And Selected a shape by clicking on it.

Now I want to get Shape object of slected shape. I have tried this but it throws exception.

```
dim shap as Excel.Shape = ExcelApp.Selection
```

I can get the shape object by iterating on ActiveSheet.Shapes or like this

```
dim shap as Excel.Shape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1)
```

But how would I know this shape is selected or not, Really need Help Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you get?  Have you tried casting `ExcelApp.Selection` to a shape?

Comment: Yes I have tried Explicit Conversion too and it gives me the same exception.
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00024439-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: Maybe try the appraoch suggested here:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/17ebd235-ccad-4f0e-89e2-030bff2f12d4?prof=required&ppud=4

Comment: In VBA you cannot use 'Dim x As Y = something' -- you have to declare the object on a separate line. See if that (and Rachel's suggestion) helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Selection.ShapeRange` to get a reference to the shape object.

Comment: Setting a shape reference to Selection.ShapeRange won't fly ... gives a Type Mismatch error. Selection.ShapeRange(1) returns a shape object rather than a range object, so doesn't error.

Comment: In addition to this answer, I've found a Microsoft docs about this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shaperange-object-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It said: "Use Selection.ShapeRange( index ), where index is the shape name or the index number, to return a single shape within the selection. The following example sets the fill foreground color for shape two in the collection of selected shapes in window one, assuming that there are at least two shapes in the selection."

Answer (score 1):

This gets a single selected Shape or Nothing if none or several shapes are selected. Obviously, you can drop the MsgBox calls.

```
Function GetSelectedShape() As Shape
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Rectangle" Then
        MsgBox "Selection is not a single shape"
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim oShapes As ShapeRange
    Set oShapes = Selection.ShapeRange

    If oShapes.Count <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Selection is not a single shape"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set GetSelectedShape = oShapes(1)

End Function
```

Comment: Did you run this? If so, what was the calling statement? In what context were you using it? I.e., do you have a short sub that shows how to call your function and what to do with the returned result? (How could selecting a Shape give a Rectangle? Also, note that if Selection = "", then TypeName(Selection)  = "Selection". So how is Selection selected prior to calling GetSelectedShape?)